# How to send mails by a play framework application without third party mail account?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, ubuntu-14.04, playframework-2.3

I am working on a play application which is hosted on an Ubuntu 14.04 server and wish to send mails (for password retrieval) by the system. Using the [Play Mailer plugin](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer), I went about just leaving the configuration blank

```
# mail
mailers.from=""
smtp.host=localhost
#smtp.port=
#smtp.ssl=
#smtp.tls=
#smtp.user=""
#smtp.password=""
```

but this results in an Exception

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : localhost:25]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
```

It worked with an Google Mail account though but I don't see the necessity to have a working account. Is there any way to send mail without a third party account? The [documentation](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer) states it as optional.

Comment: Setup a local SMTP server?

Comment: I thought about something that would not make the complexity of the system grow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Play framework nor the mentioned Mailer plugin have any built-in SMTP server so you need an external one in order to send mails. That is why a SMTP host is required by the Mailer plugin.

> smtp.host (mandatory)

The reason why authentication credentials are marked in the documentation as optional is because you may configure your SMTP server to accept connections without authentication.

For example you if your Play application and a SMPT server are in the same local network and the server is not accessible publicly then you may decide that authentication is not necessary since it is designed only for that particular application.

In a nutshell if you want to be able to send mails without any third party account you need a local SMTP server.

Comment: Cool, thanks, even if this is not the wished solution :)